# texture will not load to player in sfml

Tags: png, textures, sfml

I am trying to load a texture to my player class. I made the function set text to do this operation. but when I call it in the main loop (and I made sure it's not in the poll event) it just shows a white rectangle. I changed it to 32 bits, but it didn't work and then to 8 and that also didn't work (its original bit was 24). I also made sure that it was that the texture wasn't loading, and it is not. all responses are appreciated.

```
void setText1() {
        sf::Texture p1text;
        p1text.loadFromFile("player1.png");
        rect.setTexture(&p1text);
    }
```

main.cpp

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,800), "High noon showdown", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    player1 player1(50, 70, 85, 325);
    player2 player2(50, 70, 715, 325);
    player1.setText1();

//game loop

//movement
window.clear(sf::Color(210,180,140,100));
        player1.collidewindow1();
        player1.drawto1(window);
        player2.collidewindow2();
        player2.drawto2(window);
        window.display();
```

player1.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include "main.h"

class player1
{

public:
    //get player size and position
    player1(float x, float y, float px, float py) {
        rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(x,y));
        rect.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(px, py));
    }

    //draw player
    void drawto1(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
        window.draw(rect);
    }
    
    
    void collidewindow1() {
        //Top collision
        if(rect.getPosition().y < 0.0f) {
            rect.setPosition(rect.getPosition().x, 0.0f);
        }
        //Bottom collision
        if(rect.getPosition().y + rect.getGlobalBounds().height > 800) {
            rect.setPosition(rect.getPosition().x, 800 - rect.getGlobalBounds().height );
        }
    }
    void upfalse1() {
        up = false;
    }
    void downfalse1() {
        down = false;
    }
    void moveup1() {
        up = true;

        if(up == true){
        
        rect.move(0.0f, -5.0f * dt * 32.5f);
        }
    }
    void movedown1() {
        down = true;

        if(down == true) {

        rect.move(0.0f, 5.0f * dt * 32.5f);
        }
    }


    void setText1() {
        sf::Texture p1text;
        p1text.loadFromFile("p1.png");
        rect.setTexture(&p1text);
    }

    int getx1() {
        return rect.getPosition().x;
    }
    int gety1() {
        return rect.getPosition().y;
    }

private:
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    bool up;
    bool down;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

sf::Sprites need textures to work. They save the textures in pointer form so using temporary variable will not work. You need your texture to either be a dynamic variable or be in a place until the sprite you created is destroyed.

If you don't want to play with dynamic variables i suggest you put the texture variable into a 'player' object.

This is what's breaking your code:

```cpp
void setText1() {
        sf::Texture p1text; <- you create texture
        p1text.loadFromFile("player1.png"); <- load the texture
        rect.setTexture(&p1text); <- set the rect/sprite with texture
    } <- texutre gets deleted thus sprite/rect point to adress with no texture
```

Fix:

```cpp
class Player1
{
...

private:
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    bool up;
    bool down;
sf::Texture texture; <- void setText1() should set this texture
};
```